# java enum with value between x and y

Tags: java, variables, enums, byte, key-value

This is a simple question:

Is it possible to have an enum with a variable value ?

To be clear i would like to create an enum corresponding to an error code returned by a function which is two bytes, so i would like to do something like

```
public enum ErrorCode {
    
    ERR_NONE      ((byte)0x9000),        // No error
    ERR_PARAM     ((byte)0x8200),     // Parameter error
    ERR_DATA ((byte)0x83XX),    // XX could be any value

}
```

how to return ERR_DATA for all values beginning by 0x83 ?

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: You could make an enum where one of the fields is a `Predicate<Byte>` then put whatever conditions you like in there.

Comment: Those 'byte' casts are going to just throw away the two high-order digits of the constant, so you probably don't want them.

Comment: you could also define a high and low value to match, like `ERR_DATA(0x8300, 0x83FF)` and then check for those boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation following Dawood ibn Kareem's suggestion in comments above.

Some points:

- This implementation throws an exception if a code matches two enum values. You would need to decide whether you wanted that behaviour, or just return the first match. In that case the ordering of the enum values becomes significant.
- You can add new constructors for common cases, e.g. I have one for a value which matches a single code. You could add one for a value which matches a range of codes.
- You might also want to throw an exception if no `ErrorCode` matches the  integer code. This implementation returns `null` in that case, so you'll get an NPE if the caller doesn't check for `null`, but you won't know what value triggered it.

```java
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public enum ErrorCode {
    ERR_NONE      (0x9000),        // No error
    ERR_PARAM     (0x8200),     // Parameter error
    ERR_DATA (n -> (n >= 0x8300 && n <= 0x83FF)),    // 0x83XX
    ERR_ANOTHER_83 (0x8377);
    private final Predicate<Integer> forValue;

    ErrorCode(Predicate<Integer> matches) {
        this.forValue = matches;
    }

    ErrorCode(int singleValue) {
        this(n -> n == singleValue);
    }

    public static ErrorCode forInt(int code) {
        ErrorCode matchingCode = null;
        for (ErrorCode c : ErrorCode.values()) {
            if (c.forValue.test(code)) {
                if (matchingCode != null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("ErrorCodes " + matchingCode.name() 
                       + " and " + c.name() + " both match 0x" 
                       + Integer.toHexString(code));
                } else {
                    matchingCode = c;
                }
            }
        }
        return matchingCode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ErrorCode.forInt(0x8312));
        System.out.println(ErrorCode.forInt(0x9000));
        System.out.println(ErrorCode.forInt(0x8377));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a method which, given 0x83NN as input, returns ERR_DATA.  Done.

```
ErrorCode errorCode(int n) {
    if (n == 0x9000)
        return ERR_NONE;
    else if (n == 0x8200) 
        return ERR_PARAM;
    else if (n >= 0x8300 && n <= 0x83ff)
        return ERR_DATA;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

You have to write code to look up the value in any case.  There's no intrinsic 'associate this integer value with this enum constant, and provide a lookup for enum constant given an integer value'.

Note that, for this, there's no need to store the numeric value inside each member of the enum.  And also note that your constructor calls like ERR_NONE(0x9000) are not valid unless you've defined a suitable constructor. And if you do define a suitable constructor, you'll need to decide on a single value for the argument of ERR_DATA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it cannot be the case. According to [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html#:%7E:text=An%20enum%20type%20is%20a,the%20days%20of%20the%20week.),

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.

Comment: All that says is that a variable of type ErrorCode can have only the values ERR_NONE, ERR_PARAM, ERR_DATA, or null.  Those numbers 0x9000 etc. do not have 'enum type' and indeed for those constructor calls (like ERR_NONE(0x9000)) to be valid, the programmer needs to write a constructor that takes an integer argument, and presumably does something useful with it.